# Boost. Handy variables_map. Taking advantage of having specified the type in the options_desctription

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost

Using `boost/program_options` in c++, when I build the `options_description` I specify each option's type (`fs::path` in this case):

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc("Example");
desc.add_options()
  ("help", "Print help messages")
  ("input,i", po::value<fs::path>(), "Input folder");
```

and I build the `variables_map`

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
```

When I access the option I have to specify again their type:

```
vm["input"].as<fs::path>()
```

and not

```
vm["input"]
```

*Is there some more handy way of accessing the variables map?
Can't boost take advantage from the fact that I already specified the type of the `variable_value` stored in `vm`?*

I saw that many programmers end up in storing the option in another variable

```
fs::path input = vm["input"].as<fs::path>()
```

but I would like to avoid defining redundant variables.

Comment: Use a constant variable definition.

Comment: You mean `("input,i", fs::path(), "Input folder")`? Can I? `variables_map` hinerits from `std::map< std::string, variable_value >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you would use the `notify` feature from the [*Storage* component of the library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp337754976).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa48b8929f80b246)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    po::options_description desc("Example");

    int i = -99; // some value
    fs::path v;  // the only place where we ever specify the type!

    desc.add_options()
      ("help", "Print help messages")
      ("value,v", po::value(&i)->default_value(42),          "Input folder")
      ("input,i", po::value(&v)->default_value("TheAnswer"), "Input folder");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    notify(vm);

    std::cout << i << ", " << v << "\n";
}
```

Here the conversions as well as type-specifications themselves are implicit. Output:

```
./test
42, "TheAnswer"

./test -i /temp/path/foo --value=123
123, "/temp/path/foo"
```

Comment: This helps in having something (really) handy to use inputs afterwords. However, it requires previous declaration of all the variables. Moreover, `vm` becomes useless after notify. Right?

Comment: I specifically described it as "the _`notify`_ feature of the Storage component", linking to the documentation :) You can use that documentation to find information about [option semantics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp337727504), i.e. you can have custom notification functions. I think it's pretty much possible to do whatever you want, but I'd recommend keeping it simple. The variables are simple. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Finally, `vm` is not useless this way. It still receives the map first-hand. Notifiers **just automate** the step you did manually and found clumsy (`input = vm["input"].as<fs::path>()`). You're free to mix and match option [value styles](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/value_semantic.html).

Comment: Clear, thanks. What I meant is that this way I store the same information twice (In the variable `i` and `v` and inside `vm`). Once I have `i` and `v`, `vm` is useless as far as accessing the options value is concerned. I was wandering if there was a way to avoid both doubling the information and a using `as<>()`. The answer seems to be no. Can you update your answer with this information more explicit? I can do it myself if you prefer.

Comment: My point was indeed that you can't have your cake and eat it. `vm` contains strings, so there's *always* conversion/copy going to happen. And storage backend employs notification for automatic handling. Storage doesn't know about value semantics, including types. There is no way to parse without using the `variable_map`. So indeed is not possible to avoid the copy. I thought my answer closely matched the question. Feel free to edit the answer (and the question) to reflect the fact that you actually want to optimise for string allocations.