# boost program options short / long parameter names

Tags: c++, boost

I have implemented a routing to print out all of the options that are available in my `boost::program_options` objects along with their current values by iterating over the `po::variable_map`.

With this I can directly print the long name of the option along with its value. However, I do not know, how to retrieve the short option name from the long option name (i.e. -h from --help). Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember describing in a recent answer why `variable_map` is "too late" to know about the option descriptions:

- [Boost. Handy variables_map. Taking advantage of having specified the type in the options_desctription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891861/boost-handy-variables-map-taking-advantage-of-having-specified-the-type-in-the/31908741#31908741)

In short, the variable_map sits in the [Storage Component](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp343232256) of the library and as such is isolated from the Option Descriptions (which lives in the [Options Description Component](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp343157936)).

### What *can* you do?

You could work with the intermediate results, the raw output from the [Parsers Component](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp343221840):

> The results of parsing are returned as an instance of the [`parsed_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/program_options/reference.html#boost.program_options.parsed_options) class. Typically, that object is passed directly to the storage component. However, it also can be used directly, or undergo some additional processing

So, let's try to work out a sample here:

```
    po::parsed_options const intermediate = po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc);

    //////////////////////////////////
    // print the extended usage info as per the question
    //
    for (auto& entry : intermediate.options)
    {
        po::option_description const& opt = desc.find(entry.string_key, false, false, false); 

        std::cout << "\nActual tokens involved: ";
        for (auto& tok : entry.original_tokens)
            std::cout << "'" << tok << "' ";
        for (std::string const& v : entry.value)
            std::cout << "\nAssociated value: " << v;
        std::cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "opt.format_name()        : "        << opt.format_name()                                      << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.long_name()          : "        << opt.long_name()                                        << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('-'): "  << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_dash_for_short)  << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('/'): "  << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_slash_for_short) << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('--'): " << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_long)            << "\n";
    }
```

> **Note**: with the lookup by key, you can practically also use the `variable_map` after all.

Prints e.g.

```
Actual tokens involved: '-C' '42' 
Associated value: 42
-----------------------------------------------------------
opt.format_name()        : -C [ --compression ]
opt.long_name()          : compression
opt.canonical_display_name('-'): -C
opt.canonical_display_name('/'): /C
opt.canonical_display_name('--'): --compression

Actual tokens involved: '--name' 'santa' 
Associated value: santa
-----------------------------------------------------------
opt.format_name()        : -n [ --name ]
opt.long_name()          : name
opt.canonical_display_name('-'): -n
opt.canonical_display_name('/'): /n
opt.canonical_display_name('--'): --name
Compression level was set to 42.
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e528d75e3b14746)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/detail/parsers.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po  = boost::program_options;
namespace cls = po::command_line_style;

int main(int ac, char** av) {
    // Declare the supported options.
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("name,n", po::value<std::string>(), "specify the name")
        ("compression,C", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::parsed_options const intermediate = po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc);

    //////////////////////////////////
    // print the extended usage info as per the question
    //
    for (auto& entry : intermediate.options)
    {
        po::option_description const& opt = desc.find(entry.string_key, false, false, false); 

        std::cout << "\nActual tokens involved: ";
        for (auto& tok : entry.original_tokens)
            std::cout << "'" << tok << "' ";
        for (std::string const& v : entry.value)
            std::cout << "\nAssociated value: " << v;
        std::cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "opt.format_name()        : "        << opt.format_name()                                      << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.long_name()          : "        << opt.long_name()                                        << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('-'): "  << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_dash_for_short)  << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('/'): "  << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_slash_for_short) << "\n";
        std::cout << "opt.canonical_display_name('--'): " << opt.canonical_display_name(cls::allow_long)            << "\n";
    }

    //////////////////////////////////

    po::store(intermediate, vm);
    po::notify(vm);    

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << desc << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (vm.count("compression")) {
        std::cout << "Compression level was set to " 
            << vm["compression"].as<int>() << ".\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want you can still see how I stumbled my way through this API: [part #1](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-options-find-description-after-parse-1/) and [part #2](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-options-find-description-after-parse-2/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: If we want just the name of the option without '-' or '--' then opt.canonical_display_name(0)/opt.canonical_display_name(default_style)  seems to work. Is that correct? Is this also valid for config file options as well?

Comment: @abhishekgupta I expect so. But it's easy to check. And hard to come up with alternative theories.